# how to change the guest status node value in firebase database from it current value to another

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update the guest status in my firebase database from it initial value "Booked" to "Leaving" without creating new guest id in the database.

I wrote the code in xcode, but it not changing the value when the Exit approval button is clicked. I have done same in android app, which is connected to same firebase database, but the iOS is not updating the status as expected.

```swift
struct GuestListScreen: View {
    // State variables to manage different interactions within the screen.
    @State private var isEmergencyTapped: Bool = false
    @State private var isHomeButtonTap: Bool = false
    @State private var isQuestButtonTap: Bool = false
    @State private var isChatButtonTap: Bool = false
    @State private var isProfileButtonTap: Bool = false
    @StateObject private var guestViewModel = GuestViewModel()
    @State private var selectedGuest: GuestDetails? = nil
    @State private var guests: [GuestDetails] = []
    @State private var userUid: String?
    
    init() {
        userUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    }
    // this is the function to update the guest status in firebase database from it current value to        Leaving
    func updateGuestStatus(guestId: String, newStatus: String) {
        
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            let userUid = user.uid
            let database = Database.database()
            let guestsRef = database.reference(withPath: "users/\(userUid)/guests")
            
            let guestRef = guestsRef.child(guestId)
            
            guestRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                if var guestData = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                    guestData["status"] = newStatus
                    
                    guestRef.setValue(guestData) { error, _ in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error updating guest status: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        } else {
                            print("Guest status updated successfully")
                            self.guestViewModel.fetchGuests()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("User is not authenticated. Please log in.")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Guest List")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding([.leading, .top, .bottom], 8)
                    
                    ForEach(guests, id: \.id) { guest in
                        GuestListCard(guest: guest) {
                            selectedGuest = guest
                        }
                        .id(guest.id)
                    }
                }
            }
            BottomAppBarForEmergency(isEmergencyTapped: $isEmergencyTapped,
                                     isHomeButtonTap: $isHomeButtonTap,
                                     isQuestButtonTap: $isQuestButtonTap,
                                     isChatButtonTap: $isChatButtonTap,
                                     isProfileButtonTap: $isProfileButtonTap)
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isEmergencyTapped) {
            EmergencyScreen()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isHomeButtonTap){
            HomeScreen()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isChatButtonTap){
            MessageScreen()
            
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isQuestButtonTap){
            GuestListScreen()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isProfileButtonTap){
            ProfileScreen()
        }
        .onAppear {
            guestViewModel.fetchGuests()
        }
        .onChange(of: guestViewModel.guests) { newGuests in
            withAnimation {
                guests = newGuests.sorted(by: { $0.currentTime > $1.currentTime })
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedGuest) { guest in
            
            GuestDetailsDialog(guest: guest,  updateGuestStatus: updateGuestStatus) {
                selectedGuest = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GuestListCard: View {
    let guest: GuestDetails
    let onCardClick: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            onCardClick()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.accentColor)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    .overlay(
                        Text("\(guest.randomNumbers.map(String.init).joined(separator: ","))")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    )
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(guest.name)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text(guest.phoneNumber)
                            .font(.caption)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        Spacer()
                        if let status = guest.status {
                            Text(status)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Text("Generated at: \(formatTime(timestamp: guest.currentTime))")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                .padding(.leading, 8)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(8)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke(Color.black))
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}

<this is how i structured my guestDetailsDialog/>
struct GuestDetailsDialog: View {
    
    let guest: GuestDetails
    let updateGuestStatus: (String, String) -> Void
    let onDismiss: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                updateGuestStatus(guest.id.uuidString, "Leaving")
                onDismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Exit Approval")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                onDismiss()
                
            }) {
                Text("Detain")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .padding(16)
    }
}

struct ContentsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GuestListScreen()
                .navigationTitle("Guest List")
        }
    }
}

struct GuestDetails: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    var status: String?
    var currentTime: TimeInterval
    var randomNumbers: [Int]
    
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
              let phoneNumber = dictionary["phoneNumber"] as? String,
              let currentTime = dictionary["currentTime"] as? TimeInterval,
              let randomNumbers = dictionary["randomNumbers"] as? [Int] else {
            return nil
        }
        
        self.name = name
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.currentTime = currentTime
        self.status = dictionary["status"] as? String
        self.randomNumbers = randomNumbers
    }
}

class GuestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var guests: [GuestDetails] = []
    
    func fetchGuests() {
        let userUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
        guard let userUid = userUid else {
            
            return
        }
        
        let database = Database.database()
        let guestsRef = database.reference(withPath: "users/\(userUid)/guests")
        
        guestsRef.observe(.value) { snapshot in
            var fetchedGuests: [GuestDetails] = []
            
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                   let guestData = childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any],
                   let guest = GuestDetails(dictionary: guestData) {
                    fetchedGuests.append(guest)
                }
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.guests = fetchedGuests.sorted(by: { $0.currentTime > $1.currentTime })
            }
        }
    }
}
// bottom app bar
struct BottomAppBarForGuestList: View {
    
    let symbols:[String] = ["list.bullet", "shield.checkered", "paperplane.circle"]
    @Binding var isEmergencyTapped: Bool
    @Binding var isHomeButtonTap:  Bool
    @Binding var isQuestButtonTap: Bool
    @Binding var isChatButtonTap: Bool
    @Binding var isProfileButtonTap: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                isHomeButtonTap.toggle()
            }) {
                BottomBarButton(imageName: "house", title: "Home")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                isQuestButtonTap.toggle()
                
            }) {
                BottomBarButtonGuest(imageName: symbols[0], title: "Guest")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                isEmergencyTapped.toggle()
            }) {
                BottomBarButtonGuest(imageName: symbols[1], title: "Emergency")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                isChatButtonTap.toggle()
            }) {
                BottomBarButtonGuest(imageName: symbols[2], title: "Chat")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                
                isProfileButtonTap.toggle()
            }) {
                BottomBarButtonGuest(imageName: "person", title: "Profile")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
        .shadow(radius: 1)
    }
}

struct BottomBarButtonGuest: View {
    
    var imageName: String
    var title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: imageName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                .foregroundColor(.A)
            Text(title)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentsView()
    }
}

func formatTime(timestamp: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Comment: I recommend setting a breakpoint on each line of code inside your `updateGuestStatus` function and then stepping through that in a debugger. Check the value of each variable on each line. If you do that, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: i try to use updateGuestStatus to change the value of guest status but it not working

Comment: "it not working" is hard to help, and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugge. Hence my recommend to locally debug it on your system and tell us the result of that.

Comment: i have been able to update the status of the guest with new value but it creating new id and new guest status value instead of changing the existing value to new one

Answer (score 0):

The whole read-and-modify loop in your code looks flaky at best. If you need to know the current value, you should use a transaction.

but from what I can see, you don't need the current value at all, so I'd consider this much simpler approach:

```
func updateGuestStatus(guestId: String, newStatus: String) {
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let userUid = user.uid
        let database = Database.database()
        let guestsRef = database.reference(withPath: "users/\(userUid)/guests")            
        let guestRef = guestsRef.child(guestId)            
        let statusRef = guestRef.child("status")
                
        statusRef.setValue(newStatus) { error, _ in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error updating guest status at (statusRef): \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Guest status updated successfully")
                self.guestViewModel.fetchGuests()
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("User is not authenticated. Please log in.")
    }
}
```

If that doesn't do what you expect it to do, edit your question to show the updated code **and** the log output you get.